# Simple stop watch class

Tags: java, timer

I've made a little library where I add some functionalities from time to time that I miss in the Java standard library.

I am sad that the Java library for example has no stop watch class that allows me to measure time without the need to deal with details of a time library.

When I write library functionalities, I have the following requirements to myself:

- Keep it simple, stupid. The code has to be on point and should only do what is really needed.
- The code has to be very readable, even if this leads to some more code lines.
- The task has to be solved efficiently. Memory and calculation time should not be wasted.
- If the standard library or other stuff like that is needed, only use stable, long-lasting and modern technologies, prioritized in this order.

So this class was born. What do you think about it? Did I meet my own requirements?

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.Duration;

public class StopWatch {
    private Instant startDate;
    private Instant stopDate;
    
    public StopWatch() {
        reset();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        if (startDate == null) {
            startDate = Instant.now();
        }
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        if (stopDate == null && startDate != null) {
            stopDate = Instant.now();
        }
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        startDate = null;
        stopDate = null;
    }
    
    public long getMilli() {
        if (startDate != null && stopDate != null) {
            Duration duration = Duration.between(startDate, stopDate);
            long nanos = duration.getSeconds() * 1000000000 + duration.getNano(); 
            return nanos / 1000000;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Purpose**

The code following now is not part of the code that should be reviewed. Some people wanted me to show the use case and that it is:

I have a class thats objects calculate prime numbers. I want to measure how much time it needs to calculate these numbers, so therefore i need a stopwatch class for preventing overbloating my code with date-time-apis of my programming language.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        sw.start();
        
        PrimeNumberCalculator pnc = new PrimeNumberCalculator();
        pnc.setCurrentNumber(10000);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            pnc.calculateNextPrime();
            sb.append((i+1) + ";" + pnc.getCurrentPrimeNumber() + "\n");
        }
        
        sw.stop();
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        System.out.println(sw.getMilli());
    }
}
```

**PrimeNumberCalculator.java**

```
public class PrimeNumberCalculator {
    private long currentNumber;
    private long currentPrimeNumber;
    
    public PrimeNumberCalculator(long currentNumber) {
        this.currentNumber = currentNumber;
    }
    
    public PrimeNumberCalculator() {
        this(3);
        currentPrimeNumber = 2;
    }
    
    public long getCurrentPrimeNumber() {
        return currentPrimeNumber;
    }
    
    public void setCurrentNumber(long currentNumber) {
        this.currentNumber = currentNumber;
    }
    
    public void calculateNextPrime() {
        boolean isPrime;
        do {
            isPrime = true;
            for (long i = 2; i < currentNumber; i++) {
                if (currentNumber % i == 0 && currentNumber != 2) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (isPrime) {
                currentPrimeNumber = currentNumber;
            }
            
            currentNumber++;
        } while (!isPrime);
    }
}
```

The class is also needed in my own Minesweeper implementation, where players can play against the time and be ranked in criterias of time needed.

Comment: A couple of comments: (1) time is more important than date, so `startTime/stopTime` would be more readable. (2) You should write some code snippets showing example desired usage of your class. One thing I notice is that you can only use it once, whereas other stopwatches allow you to look at "lap times" by calling "getMilli()" multiple times.

Comment: A quick search on the project I am working on reveals I have 4 different StopWatch implementations available (Cucumber, Apache Commons, Spring and Google Common). Are you really sure you need to make your own? :) Have you looked at those to see what other people consider to be useful features?

Comment: Yes, because most of projects I do are small. And I dont want to add a giant library for one or maybe 3 simple tasks, so I have my own little library. Maybe when i make something big as Office 365 or Minecraft, I will think about that

Comment: The size of your codebase should have very little correlation to the amount of dependencies there are. Or... one could even say that the less code and more dependencies you have, the better it is, because you are spending less time reinventing things that have already been done. That being said, I do recognize the value in tinkering and trying to make things yourself. The question is: do you gain anything by trying to reduce the size of your deployment package? When do the returns diminish?

Comment: I wonder if this could lead to additional security vulnerabilities... My minesweeper implementation for example has 400 to 500 lines of code. Than i would need, let us say, 2 giant libraries like guava and than i am using 5 of maybe 5000 methods. This just feels wrong, my female intuition says, and i am male, lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a library class, JavaDocs should be given (well, here the interface is so small and well-named that one can easily guess the tasks of the methods, but anyway).

As already said, the `getMilli()` method should be replaced with a `getDuration()` one. Your conversion to millis not only includes ugly computation code, but also cripples the available resolution. And if some user wants milliseconds, there's the `Duration.toMillis()` method.

Comment: I'd argue that for such small utility (even library) cost of in-code-comments (hurting maintainability, being another place where information about code is stored - that needs to be changed with the code) makes them exactly harmful.

Answer (score 4):

Silently ignoring a method call when it has been done in an invalid state should never be the correct approach. Calling `start()` when the stop watch has already been started is a programming error so it should not just "do nothing."

It is unclear what the code is used for. Is it for debugging or profiling? Do you use the result in program logic?

If it is for profiling, one of the undesired qualities of using stop watces is that it litters production code with variables that are not related to the application logic. I would rather have a static stop watch that stores it's state in a thread local so that I only have to call `StopWatch.start();` and `StopWatch.stop(duration -> log.debug("Execution took {}", duration));` to make it work. Pass an identifier if you need several watches running. Probably have the implementation check a system property (or Spring profile, etc) to see if it should run or do nothing so that I don't have to change the code when it goes to production (or add even more undesired boolean variables to decide if profiling should be done).

Answer (score 3):

- As mentioned in the comments, `startTime` is more sensible than `startDate`
- in testing, I found `Instant` to have resolution issues; see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689231/313768 . For short times, `nanoTime()` is more appropriate.
- Do not offer a `getMilli`; that isn't the responsibility of this class. Just offer a generic `Duration`.
- Consider simplifying your usage contract so that the start time is immutable, and the stop time is set on closure of an `AutoCloseable`.

### Suggested

```
import java.time.Duration;


public class StopWatch implements AutoCloseable {
    private final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    private Long stopTime = null;

    public void stop() {
        stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public Duration getLength() {
        return Duration.ofNanos(stopTime - startTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        stop();
    }
}


///////



import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
        try (watch) {
            out.println("Hello world");
        }
        out.printf("That took %.1f us%n", watch.getLength().toNanos()/1e3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I find this attempt unnatural. Object-Design should be oriented on the real world. You can start, stop and reset a watch, but in your code theres just a watch in a try statement and a very technical but unnatural way of getting its result.

Comment: @DexterThorn OO design should be based on the real world, to a point. This class does not model a "real" stop watch; it models a timer wrapped around a piece of code. A `try`-with-resources is a natural way to wrap code.

Comment: Isn't `Autoclosable` overengineering here? There is no real external resource needing closing (there is **a** external resource, tho - system clock).

Comment: @Azahe `AutoCloseable` is cheap. It only requires implementing one quite simple method. The paradigm of wrapping code and having something happen at the end no matter what else happens is a common one; `AutoCloseable` is not only useful to manage resources. This pattern is seen across other languages as well; see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Comment: By "overengineering" I didn't mean expensive. I do recognize the paradigm and absolutely agree that it is usable idea - I just don't think `Autoclosable` is the right realization of it (btw. have you seen my post with passing lambda to stopwatch - it doesn't need implementing any interface and has the same benefits). We only need `Autoclosable` when we open the resource in one context and when we close it in another - which here (seems to me) is not necessary. Also I'd argue that not stopping the timer on application exit is absolutely acceptable - so that aspect seems also unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

From the design perspective - have you considered making the class a pure function? I'd see its api like (keeping naming similar):

```java
long milis = StopWatch.measureInMilis(() -> {... measured logic as runnable...})
```

Note that in this stateless approach:

1. your code becomes almost impossible to use incorrectly - it usually is a sign of better design (client code is unable to call start or stop twice)
2. Implementation becomes simpler - you don't need ifs for checking edge cases
3. Code becomes easier to test - you don't need to reset the clock between tests (speaking of, you didn't need it in the first place - as you could just create new instance per test)
4. Single usage of utility means lesser coupling with the client code - if you ever wanted to refactor this solution it would be less things to change
5. `StopWatch` becomes thread safe for free

Apart from the above please note that *currently* your code has big external implicit dependency - on a system clock which makes is generally difficult, and slow, to test - but it might be a conscious decision as this implicit character of the dependency makes this code easier to use (you don't need to set this dependency up). If some business logic were to depend on that it would also make this logic more difficult to test - which might be unwanted side effect in bigger applications,

Also the final calculation seems rather clunky - `Duration` has a method `toMillis()` that would spare you unnecessary manual calculations.

Summing it all up, consider alternative implementation:

```java
public class StopWatch {

    public static long measureInMillis(Runnable operation) {
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        operation.run();
        Instant end = Instant.now();
        return Duration.between(start, end).toMillis();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I try to avoid lambdas / additional code indentations / anonym classes where it is possible.

Comment: Why? It is part of java since version 8 - do you need compatibility with older versions? I firmly believe that lambdas are worth using if design becomes objectively better thanks to them.

Comment: No, lambdas just make things more complicated. I even would say that using lambdas without a special need for them make the code look worse.

Comment: How exactly do they make the code more complicated? What would be defined as such *special need* justifying their usage - can you give an example? Also, how do they make the code "look" worse? Do you consider above example to look worse than the code you proposed? Why?

Comment: Because when your code consists of simple method calls, its the best. Lambdas and so on are more complex than simple method calls.

Lambdas are nice but when you dont really need them I think you should not use them.

Comment: Why is it best when it consists of simple method calls (do you mean like in procedural style)? Why do you consider lambdas complex (what makes them so)? I am still keen to see any example justifying lambdas usage. I know that these questions may be irritating but I am really trying to understand your point of view.

Comment: Lambdas in Java are basically syntactical sugar for anonymous classes with one method. And invoking anonymous classes and implementing their method is basically more complex than a pure method call. Yes, I think, procedural code has to be preferred other something like this whenever possible. But thats just an opionion.

Comment: But I noticed now that your approach has a clear advantage, i totally forgot: With your approach the object cant have an invalid state, and this is of course great and a lambda therefore maybe neccessary.

Answer (score 2):

A broader view of development scenario, skip it for a narrow approach of code reviewing. The code snippet from [one of the answers to this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272069) could be a [unit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) that is an easy maintainable alternative to technical documentation or live documentation linking requirements with the developed solution to the extent that any change of the implementation that breaks the requirements is a compile time error. It worth mentioning the [Test-driven development (T.D.D.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) approach of software development for its concern over the efficiency and maintainability despite its low relevance for the subject at hand.

With only purpose of having a complete depict of a possible alternative consider following implementation for the requirements listed by early mentioned answer.

```
public class StopWatch {

    private ChronoUnit chronoUnit;
    private NanoWatch watcher;
    private AtomicReference<Long> startNanosHolder;
    private AtomicReference<Long> endNanosHolder;
    private boolean timing;

    private static class Builder {
        private ChronoUnit chronoUnit;
        private boolean timing;

        private Builder() {}

        public StopWatch.Builder timing(boolean timingEnabled) {
            this.timing = timingEnabled;
            return this;
        }

        public StopWatch.Builder timeMeasureOf(ChronoUnit chronoUnit) {
        this.chronoUnit = chronoUnit;
        return this;
        }

    public StopWatch build() {
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch(this.timing);
            stopWatch.chronoUnit = this.chronoUnit;
            return stopWatch;
        }
    }

    public static StopWatch.Builder builder() {
        return new StopWatch.Builder();
    }

    private StopWatch(boolean timing) {
        this.chronoUnit = ChronoUnit.NANOS;
        this.timing = timing;
        this.watcher = NanoWatch.valueOf(this.timing);
        this.startNanosHolder = new AtomicReference<Long>();
        this.endNanosHolder = new AtomicReference<Long>();
    }

    public StopWatch measureOf(ChronoUnit unit) {
        this.chronoUnit = unit;
        return this;
    }

    public StopWatch start() {
        if (startNanosHolder.get() != null) {
            return this;
        }
        this.watcher.time(startNanosHolder);
        return this;
    }

    public StopWatch stop() {
        if (startNanosHolder.get() == null || endNanosHolder.get() != null) {
            return this;
        }
        this.watcher.time(endNanosHolder);
    
        return this;
    }

    private boolean isTiming() {
        return startNanosHolder.get() != null && endNanosHolder.get() == null;
    }

    public Optional<Long> measure() {
        if (!this.timing) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        long endNanos = this.isTiming() ? System.nanoTime() : this.endNanosHolder.get();

        return this.watcher.measure(startNanosHolder.get(), endNanos).map(this::convert);
    }

    public Long convert(Duration toConvert) {

        return ChronoUnitConverter.valueOf(this.chronoUnit)
                                  .map(chronoUnitConverter -> chronoUnitConverter.convert(toConvert)).orElse(null);
    }

    private enum ChronoUnitConverter {

        TO_SECONDS(ChronoUnit.SECONDS) {
            public long convert(Duration toConvert) {
                return toConvert.toMillis();
            }
        }
        , TO_MILIS(ChronoUnit.MILLIS) {
            public long convert(Duration toConvert) {
                return toConvert.toMillis();
            }
        }
        , TO_NANOS(ChronoUnit.NANOS) {
            public long convert(Duration toConvert) {
                return toConvert.toMillis();
            }
        };

        private ChronoUnit toConvertTo;

        private ChronoUnitConverter(ChronoUnit toConvertTo) {
            this.toConvertTo = toConvertTo;
        }

        public long convert(Duration toConvert) {
            return toConvert.toSeconds();
        }

        public static Optional<ChronoUnitConverter> valueOf(ChronoUnit chronoUnit) {
            Optional<ChronoUnitConverter> toReturn = Optional.empty();
            for (ChronoUnitConverter converter : ChronoUnitConverter.values()) {
                if (chronoUnit == converter.toConvertTo) {
                    toReturn = Optional.of(converter);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return toReturn;
        }
    }

    private enum NanoWatch {
        TIMELESS()
        , TIMER() {
            public void time(AtomicReference<Long> timeNanosHolder) {
                timeNanosHolder.set(System.nanoTime());
            }

            public Optional<Duration> measure(Long startNanos, Long endNanos) {
                return Optional.of(Duration.of(endNanos - startNanos, ChronoUnit.NANOS));
            }
        };

        public void time(AtomicReference<Long> timeNanosHolder) { }

        public Optional<Duration> measure(Long startNanos, Long endNanos) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        public static NanoWatch valueOf(boolean timed) {
            return (timed) ? TIMER : TIMELESS;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update to question update:** After updating the question most of the [requirements exploratory answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270994) is obsolete. Following up the updates there might be alternative solutions, although arguable from [K.I.S.S principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) stand point, that along with readability addresses maintainability and immutability too implementing [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design patterns.

An exploratory use case might illustrate possible features

```
public class StopWatchExplorer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StopWatch stopWatch = StopWatch.builder()
                                       .timing((args.length > 0) ? Boolean.valueOf(args[0]) : false) // dynamically enable timing
                                       .timeMeasureOf(ChronoUnit.SECONDS) // optional customisation of time unit
                                       .build();
        boolean verbose = (args.length > 1) ? Boolean.valueOf(args[1]) : false; // dynamically enable intermediate reads
        boolean processing = true;
        stopWatch.start();
        while (processing) {

            // processing = //..... sequential process

            if (verbose) { // intermediate reads
                stopWatch.measure()
                         .ifPresent(time -> System.out.println(String.format("Elapsed: %s sec", time)));
            }
        }

        stopWatch.stop()
                 .measure()
                 .ifPresent(time -> System.out.println(String.format("Calculation time: %s sec", time)));
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a follow-up to [your previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270994/120114)? if so, perhaps it makes sense to edit that answer instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: I dont understand where you implemented "KISS" here. My code for example just uses start, stop and getMillis. Your code in comparison has much more complexity and code lines and method calls for just doing the same thing. And implementing a pattern also makes the code more complex :/ But I give you an upvote for your idea and effort

Answer (score 1):

By the way is implemented the timing can be achieved in two steps: instantiate and start the timing thus it might worth addressing thread safeness that could be achieved in terms of listed requirements using the guarantees offered by the JVM for static initialisers detailed by section [12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html) of JLS, namely the guarantee that static initialisers are thread safe and run when the encapsulating class is loaded by the class loader. Taking use of the offered guarantees thread safeness without explicit synchronisation could be achieved along with lazy initialization.

K.I.S.S principles for a complex use case might be complicated to follow simultaneously for both the usage of the implemented solution and the implementation. When in doubt it should balance to keep simple the exposed interface although the implementation complexity may increase.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class StopWatch {

    private ChronoUnit chronoUnit;
    private NanoWatch watcher;

    public static class Builder {
        private ChronoUnit chronoUnit;
        private boolean timing;

        private Builder() { }

        public StopWatch.Builder timing(boolean timingEnabled) {

            this.timing = timingEnabled;

            return this;
        }

        public StopWatch.Builder timeMeasureOf(ChronoUnit chronoUnit) {

            this.chronoUnit = chronoUnit;

            return this;
        }

        public StopWatch build() {

            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch(this.chronoUnit);
            stopWatch.watcher = NanoWatch.valueOf(this.timing);

            return stopWatch;
        }
    }

    public static StopWatch.Builder builder() {

        return new StopWatch.Builder();
    }

    private StopWatch() {

        this(ChronoUnit.NANOS);
    }

    private StopWatch(ChronoUnit chronoUnit) {

        this.chronoUnit = chronoUnit;
    }

    public StopWatch measureOf(ChronoUnit unit) {

        this.chronoUnit = unit;

        return this;
    }

    public StopWatch start() {

        this.watcher.start();

        return this;
    }

    public StopWatch stop() {

        if ( this.watcher.startNano == null || this.watcher.stopNano != null) { return this; }

        this.watcher.stop();

        return this;
    }

    private boolean isTiming() {

        return this.watcher.startNano != null && this.watcher.stopNano == null;
    }

    public Long measure() {

        if (!this.isTiming()) { return null; }

        long endNano = this.isTiming() ? System.nanoTime() : this.watcher.stopNano;

        return this.convert(Duration.of(endNano - this.watcher.startNano, ChronoUnit.NANOS));
    }

    public Long convert(Duration toConvert) {

        return ChronoUnitConverter.valueOf(this.chronoUnit).convert(toConvert);
    }

    private static class NanoWatch {

        private static final class StartNanoHolder {
            private static final long TIME = System.nanoTime(); // thread safe read of time
        }

        private static final class EndNanoHolder {
            private static final long TIME = System.nanoTime(); // thread safe read of time
        }

        private static final NanoWatch TIMER = new NanoWatch() {

            public void start() {

                this.startNano = StartNanoHolder.TIME; // lazy initialization 
            }

            public void stop() {

                if ( startNano == null ) { return; }

                this.stopNano = EndNanoHolder.TIME; // lazy initialization
            }
        };

        private static final NanoWatch TIMELESS = new NanoWatch();

        public static NanoWatch valueOf(boolean timed) {
            return (timed) ? TIMER : TIMELESS;
        }

        protected Long startNano;
        protected Long stopNano;

        public void start() {}
        public void stop() {}
    }

    private enum ChronoUnitConverter {

        TO_SECONDS(ChronoUnit.SECONDS) {
            public long convert(Duration toConvert) {
                return toConvert.toMillis();
            }
        }
        , TO_MILIS(ChronoUnit.MILLIS) {
            public long convert(Duration toConvert) {
                return toConvert.toMillis();
            }
        }
        , TO_NANOS(ChronoUnit.NANOS) {
            public long convert(Duration toConvert) {
                return toConvert.toMillis();
            }
        };

        private ChronoUnit toConvertTo;

        private ChronoUnitConverter(ChronoUnit toConvertTo) {
            this.toConvertTo = toConvertTo;
        }

        public long convert(Duration toConvert) {
            return toConvert.toSeconds();
        }

        public static ChronoUnitConverter valueOf(ChronoUnit chronoUnit) {

            ChronoUnitConverter toReturn = TO_NANOS;
            for (ChronoUnitConverter converter : ChronoUnitConverter.values()) {
                if (chronoUnit == converter.toConvertTo) {
                    toReturn = converter;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return toReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> to measure time without the need to deal with details of a time library

could be achieved following the [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) factoring out the conversion from nano seconds to a different time unit to its own class, or for convenience its own enum.

```
public enum NanoConverter {

    TO_SECONDS {
        public long convert(long toConvert) {
            return toConvert / 1000000000;
        }
        public String unitMeasureLabel() {
            return "sec";
        }
    }
    , TO_MILLIS {
        public long convert(long toConvert) {
            return toConvert / 1000000;
        }
        public String unitMeasureLabel() {
            return "milli sec";
        }
    }
    , TO_MICROS {
        public long convert(long toConvert) {
            return toConvert / 1000;
        }
        
        public String unitMeasureLabel() {
            return "micro sec";
        }
    }
    , TO_NANOS;

    public long convert(long toConvert) {
        return toConvert;
    }

    public String unitMeasureLabel() {
        return "nano sec";
    }
}
```

The `StopWatch` thread safe implementation concern being only to provide the time, will be purged from the dependence of a time library.

```
public class StopWatch {
   
    private NanoWatch watcher;

    public static class Builder {

        private boolean timing;

        private Builder() { }

        public StopWatch.Builder timing(boolean timingEnabled) {

            this.timing = timingEnabled;

            return this;
        }

        public StopWatch build() {

            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.watcher = NanoWatch.valueOf(this.timing);

            return stopWatch;
        }
    }

    public static StopWatch.Builder builder() {

        return new StopWatch.Builder();
    }

    private StopWatch() { }

    public StopWatch start() {

        this.watcher.start();

        return this;
    }

    public StopWatch stop() {

        if ( this.watcher.startNano == null || this.watcher.stopNano != null ) {
            return this;
        }

        this.watcher.stop();

        return this;
    }

    private boolean isTiming() {

        return this.watcher.startNano != null && this.watcher.stopNano == null;
    }

    public Long measure() {

        if ( !this.isTiming() ) { return null; }

        long endNano = this.isTiming() ? System.nanoTime() : this.watcher.stopNano;

        return endNano - this.watcher.startNano;
    }

    private static class NanoWatch {

        private static final class StartNanoHolder {
            private static final long TIME = System.nanoTime(); // thread safe
        }

        private static final class EndNanoHolder {
            private static final long TIME = System.nanoTime(); thread safe
        }

        private static final NanoWatch TIMER = new NanoWatch() {

            public void start() {

                this.startNano = StartNanoHolder.TIME; // lazy initialization
            }

            public void stop() {

                if ( startNano == null ) { return; }

                this.stopNano = EndNanoHolder.TIME; // lazy initialization
            }
        };

        private static final NanoWatch TIMELESS = new NanoWatch();

        public static NanoWatch valueOf(boolean timed) {
            return (timed) ? TIMER : TIMELESS;
        }

        protected Long startNano;
        protected Long stopNano;

        public void start() { }

        public void stop() { }
    }
}
```

With concern dedicated implementation the time watching use case could be easily fine grained to the extent of dynamically choosing the adequate convertor for the measured duration, durations greater than one thousand nano seconds being displayed in micro seconds, durations greater than one million nano seconds being displayed in milli seconds and so on if needed.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class StopWatchExplorer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StopWatch stopWatch = StopWatch.builder()
                                       .timing(StopWatchExplorer.getBooleanArgument((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "false", "timing"))
                                       .build();

        NanoConverter converter = NanoConverter.TO_SECONDS;
        AtomicReference<NanoConverter> adequateConverterHolder = new AtomicReference<NanoConverter>(converter);
        boolean verbose = StopWatchExplorer.getBooleanArgument((args.length > 1) ? args[1] : "false", "verbose");
        boolean processing = true;
        stopWatch.start();

        while (processing) {

            // processing =

            if (verbose) {
                Optional.ofNullable(stopWatch.measure())
                        .map(nano -> adequateConverterHolder.get().convert(nano))
                        .ifPresent(nano -> { 

                            System.out.println(String.format("Elapsed: %s %s"
                                              , nano
                                              , adequateConverterHolder.get().unitMeasureLabel()));

                            NanoConverter adequateConverter = StopWatchExplorer.pickConverterFor(nano);
                            if ( adequateConverterHolder.get() != adequateConverter) {
                                adequateConverterHolder.set(adequateConverter);                                                       
                            }
                         });
            }
        }

        Optional.ofNullable(stopWatch.stop().measure())
                .map(nano -> converter.convert(nano))
                .ifPresent(time ->     System.out.println(String.format("Calculation time: %s sec", time)));
    }

    private static boolean getBooleanArgument(String timing, String environmentVariableName) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(timing)
                       .map(string -> Boolean.valueOf(string.toUpperCase()))
                       .orElseGet(() -> false);
    }

    private static NanoConverter pickConverterFor(long numberOfNanoSeconds) {
        
        NanoConverter converterToReturn = NanoConverter.TO_NANOS;

        if (1000 > numberOfNanoSeconds) {
            converterToReturn = NanoConverter.TO_MICROS;
        } else if (1000000 > numberOfNanoSeconds) {
            converterToReturn = NanoConverter.TO_MILLIS;
        } else if ( 1000000000 > numberOfNanoSeconds) {
            converterToReturn = NanoConverter.TO_SECONDS;
        }
        return converterToReturn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Other than below the implementation follows the listed requirements.

> The code has to be on point and should only do what is really needed.

> Did I meet my own requirements?

Unless `really needed` is optional, thus skippable, it should be detailed for a relevant opinion. For instance would `watching since` be a requisite feature?

Comment: This answer reviews the requirements rather than the code. Since this is the code review site there needs to be observations about the code as well.